# How do you bind the dependencies of the service dll's at that layer in .NET Core

Tags: dependency-injection, asp.net-core, single-responsibility-principle

I would like to make a contained libraries/services in the new .NET Core world. Basically I have several SASS products:

ServiceProduct1: has a repository layer that the UI/Composistion root layer doesn't need to know about.

ServiceProduct2: has a repository layer that the UI/Composistion root layer doesn't need to know about. Has an Email service in it as well.

These two service products are used in multiple applications, but the consuming application has to know to bind the interfaces hidden in the repository. Also the Email service uses Dependency Injection and it has to be 
bound in the consuming application, even though it is used by a service.

Prior to .NET Core I would have used Recursion to search the dlls for things to bind:

```cs
public static IKernel LoadAssemblies(IKernel kernel)
{
    var type = typeof(INinjectDependency);
    var dependencies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
        .SelectMany(x => x.GetMatchingTypesInAssembly(y => type.IsAssignableFrom(y) && y.IsClass));
    var assemblies = dependencies.Select(Assembly.GetAssembly).Distinct();
    kernel.Load(assemblies);
    return kernel;
}
```

Then in the consumed services you would do all your binding.

I am not using Ninject any longer but the concept is the same. Now unless you swap to publish the dll's on build, you cannot use this approach anymore. I do not want to publish my dll's.

Is there another way to handle this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A lot of the documentation floating around points specifically to the implementation of `ASP.NET Core`, so I can see why this is confusing. The answer is rather simple. If your services are full executables, i.e.; when compiled they generate an `*.exe` then you need to wire-up you services at startup - somewhere near the main entry point. If your service is simply a `*.dll`, then you must have a host application (executable) that wires up the dependencies for you - and then hands you the service collection, such that you can construct an `IServiceProvider`.

Here is a great article on [`Dependency Injection with .NET Core`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt707534.aspx). Here is the example of how you would achieve this:

```cs
public class Host
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        IServiceCollection serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
        ConfigureServices(serviceCollection);

        var application = new Application(serviceCollection);

        // Run
        // ...
    }

    static void ConfigureServices(
        IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
    {
        ILoggerFactory loggerFactory = new Logging.LoggerFactory();
        serviceCollection.AddInstance<ILoggerFactory>(loggerFactory);
    }
}
```

There are some standard naming conventions here, notice the `ConfigureServices`. Then the `Application` object is defined as such:

```cs
public class Application
{
    public IServiceProvider Services { get; set; }
    public ILogger Logger { get; set; }

    public Application(IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
    {
        ConfigureServices(serviceCollection);

        // The service-provider is not built until all services are configured.
        Services = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();

        Logger = 
            Services.GetRequiredService<ILoggerFactory>()
                    .CreateLogger<Application>();

        Logger.LogInformation("Application created successfully.");
    }

    public void MakePayment(PaymentDetails paymentDetails)
    {
        Logger.LogInformation(
            $"Begin making a payment { paymentDetails }");
        IPaymentService paymentService =
            Services.GetRequiredService<IPaymentService>();
        // ...
    }

    void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
    {
        serviceCollection.AddSingleton<IPaymentService, PaymentService>();
    }
}
```

We can now imagine that the interface and corresponding implementation of the payment service looks something like this:

```cs
public class PaymentService: IPaymentService
{
    public ILogger Logger { get; }

    public PaymentService(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        Logger = loggerFactory?.CreateLogger<PaymentService>();
        if (Logger == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(loggerFactory));
        }
        Logger.LogInformation("PaymentService created");
    }
}
```

**Note**

This does not have to be an `ASP.NET Core` application.